# Exclude row names from R Shiny renderTable

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am using the renderTable function from the R Shiny package and it is returning a table with row names. Ideally I want a table to be displayed with only two columns, one for 'Month' and one for 'Value'. The output I currently get includes the row names. I have tried a few things to exclude row names but was unsuccessful. Any thoughts?

```
output$valueTable <- renderTable({
if(input$table_view == TRUE){
  data.frame(Month = Month(), Value = valueData()[,"Value"])
}  
})
```

Comment: `renderTable` has a `...` which passes options to `xtable`. `xtable` has an `include.rownames` options. Try using `include.rownames = FALSE` as an option in `renderTable`

Answer (score 35):

this instruction is working for me

```
output$summaryTable <- renderTable({
       df()$donnees         
    }, 
    include.rownames=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 5):

Into your init code, put

```
options(xtable.include.rownames=F)
options(xtable.include.colnames=F)
```

this will disable it for all tables in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include `row.names=NULL` inside your data.frame call.

```
data.frame(Month = Month(), Value = valueData()[,"Value"], row.names=NULL)
```

If you already have a data frame(df), then you could do: `row.names(myDF) <- NULL`

Comment: I have added row.names=NULL and it had no impact on the shiny output.

Comment: @rrbest I haven't tried it with shiny but it worked for me with my regular code. I think to write some test code for shiny would take some  effort. Is it possible if you can paste your code/snippet for both ui.R and server.R.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
output$valueTable <- renderTable({
   if(input$table_view == TRUE){
      data.frame(Month = Month(), Value = valueData()[,"Value"])
   }  
}, rownames = FALSE)
```

Comment: please explain your answere.

Comment: if you are writing "rownames = FALSE" with renderTable, It's simply means that you don't want the name of rows in you output. you can also avoide column names to just by adding  " colnames = FALSE"

Comment: Maybe add the explanation to your answer.