# How do I suppress row names when using DT::renderDataTable in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

As per the explanation in section 2.3 [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/), I can remove rownames for a datatable by setting `rownames = FALSE`

[image]

How do I suppress row names when using `DT::renderDataTable` in R shiny? The following doesn't work because if you look at the [dataTables options reference](http://datatables.net/reference/option/) there is no rownames option

```
  output$subsettingTable <- DT::renderDataTable(
    subsetTable(), filter = 'top', server = FALSE, 
    options = list(pageLength = 5, autoWidth = TRUE, rownames= FALSE
    ))
```

My question is similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669150/exclude-row-names-from-r-shiny-rendertable). The answers there are for `renderTable` and I've tried making the answers there work with `DT::renderDataTable` with zero success.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Please be very careful to read the help pages of functions to know which argument belongs to which function. In your case, the `rownames` argument belongs to the `datatable()` function, but you actually put it inside the `options` argument, and that is certainly wrong. `DT::renderDataTable()` accepts either a data object or a table widget as its first argument (again, please read its help page), so either of the following expressions should work:

```
DT::renderDataTable(datatable(
    subsetTable(), filter = 'top', server = FALSE, 
    options = list(pageLength = 5, autoWidth = TRUE),
    rownames= FALSE
))

DT::renderDataTable(
    subsetTable(), filter = 'top', server = FALSE, 
    options = list(pageLength = 5, autoWidth = TRUE),
    rownames= FALSE
)
```

In the latter case, `rownames = FALSE` is passed to `datatable()` internally, per documentation of the `...` argument of the help page.