# Can't hide columns AND set rownames = FALSE in Shiny DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I created a data table in Shiny that uses DT to style values based on the values in a set of hidden columns. The table shows whether Units of a company have hit their goals for Calls and Emails.

The problem is that when I hide the columns (using `columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(4, 5), visible = FALSE))`), I can no longer use `rownames = FALSE` under the `datatable()` call: the table displays with no data. Does anyone know how I can get both these options to work together?

I've used the following articles:

https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html

[How do I suppress row names when using DT::renderDataTable in R shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486738/how-do-i-suppress-row-names-when-using-dtrenderdatatable-in-r-shiny)

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

x <- tibble(
  Unit = c("Sales", "Marketing", "HR"), 
  Calls = c(100, 150, 120), 
  Emails = c(200, 220, 230), 
  Calls_goal = c(1, 0, 0), 
  Emails_goal = c(0, 1, 1)
)


ui <- fluidPage(

   mainPanel(
         DT::dataTableOutput("table")
      )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

   output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

     # Can't use both visible = FALSE and rownames = FALSE

     datatable(x, 
               options = list(
                 columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(4, 5), visible = FALSE)) # THIS
              ), 
              rownames = TRUE) %>% # OR THIS
       formatStyle(
         columns = c('Calls', 'Emails'), 
         valueColumns = c('Calls_goal', 'Emails_goal'), 
         color = styleEqual(c(1, 0), c("red", "black"))
       ) 

   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is this how you want the output to look like : 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpXkK.png

Comment: I wanted to remove the index numbers on the far left. The answer by @JonnyCrunch solved it - thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As rownames are also a column, when you set them to false, yo need to reindex the columns you want to hide. So, in your particular case, column 5 no longer exist. Now it is number 4, and the 4th is the 3rd, so your code should look like:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    # Can't use both visible = FALSE and rownames = FALSE

    datatable(x,  rownames=F,
              options = list(
                columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(3, 4), visible = FALSE) # THIS
              )
             ))  %>% # OR THIS
      formatStyle(
        columns = c('Calls', 'Emails'), 
        valueColumns = c('Calls_goal', 'Emails_goal'), 
        color = styleEqual(c(1, 0), c("red", "black"))
      ) 

  })
}
```